# Is there VS intellisense for Umbraco XSLT extensions?

Tags: xslt, intellisense, umbraco

Is it possible to get in Visual Studio code intellisense into XSLT extension functions. 
For example when I write:

`<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.`

I would get a list of all functions/methods available under "umbraco."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do this.